# Debugging an app outside XCode on different version of OSX (view exceptions, logs, ...)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'am developing on Lion 10.7 an XCode 4.2 beta.
I need to test my app on Snow Leopard and catch crashes, NSLog etc, without XCode.
In Snow Leopard the 10.7 SDK is missing, and I can't compile and use the embedded debugging suite of XCode.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Discovered that Console will trace all my app NSLog / crashes.

Comment: You can also navigate inside your app's bundle, and launch the executable in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, I think you need to download the Xcode 4.2 beta for both Lion and Snow Leopard. These are two different versions. Get them from the Mac App Store or Apple's Developer website.

Comment: Searching on developer site, the latest Snow Leopard version available is XCode 4.0.2 with 10.6 sdk

Comment: I'm guessing that you're just a Mac Developer? iOS Developers can get this under iOS beta.